# Linux user apache has no permission to file which it owns

Tags: php, linux, permissions

So I am trying to get shell_exec to give me the response of the program, but it is not giving me any response when I put it into echo. I have tried rewriting the output variable without a input variable, and have tried to produce errors hoping the error would give me some sort of output, but still nothing. Here is the code I am having issues with

```
<?php
$key = $_GET['key'];

$output = shell_exec("node totp.js ".$key."");
echo "Your output is = $output";
?>
```

Thanks!

Edit:
I tried defining where node is `/usr/bin/node` and where the totp.js is `/var/www/html/totp.js` and it gives an error in my log: No such file or directory. I took off everything other than trying to execute node, and I get the same no such file error. When I go back to what I had to begin with, I now get an error that command is not found, which was not appearing before. Is there a way to allow PHP to roam outside of the execution folder, I.E. the htdocs/html folder?

Edit 2:
Tried changing permissions, chowning, discovered my PHP runs under the user apache, which now owns and has 755 permissions to my entire web folder, and now it recognizes the /usr/bin/node.... but it has no permissions. I have tried adding permissions in every possible way, I've tried giving it 777 although I knew I would not leave it at that, and it still has no permission to access it. I am clueless, and I guess this has become a linux issue rather than a php issue... lol - Also changing the title of the post as it is no longer a shell_exec issue, it is an issue with permissions

Edit 3: Something is royally wrong, it now gives 2 error messages. One is "No such file or directory" and the other is "Permission denied". It gives both, leading me to believe it is running on 2 seperate users/2 seperate locations. Idk what I should do, so I am going to reset my server as I have not done much, and start again. Saving the code first to see if that clears it up for me.

Comment: Documentation says "Return Values: The output from the executed command or null if an error occurred or the command produces no output." So likely an error occurred or the command produces no output. I'd assume `node` is not in the path or user does not have permission to run it. Also use `escapeshellarg()`.

Comment: I'd recommend using `exec()` so you can capture the return code, which will give you a better idea what's happening.

Comment: What @miken32 states `/path/to/node totp.js` and depending, maybe `/path/to/node /wherever/this/is/totp.js`

Comment: Thank you @miken32 for that, and thank you @AbraCadaver for the explanation! Can I ask what using `escapeshellarg()` would accomplish that would help me solve this issue?

Comment: It wouldn't help with this problem, it just means you won't be letting the outside world run arbitrary commands on your server. That's something people generally like to avoid ;)

Comment: good point @miken32 lol. I tried defining where node is `/usr/bin/node` and where the totp.js is `/var/www/html/totp.js` and it gives an error in my log: No such file or directory. I took off everything other than trying to execute node, and I get the same no such file error. Is PHP stuck/limited to the html folder in httpd?